# Discord.js how to make my bot notify me whenever it is added to a server?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like a command that sends a message on a channel, whenever my bot is added or removed from a server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Client event, [`guildCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) and [`guildDelete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildDelete) is emitted whenever the bot joins and leaves the guild respectively which requires `Guild` object as a param. Inside those event, you can get the specific channel that you want to send the message to.

Eg:

```
Client.on('guildCreate',guild=>{ 
    client.channels.cache.get("channel_id").send(`Joined the server ${guild.name}`);
});

Client.on('guildDelete',guild=>{ 
    client.channels.cache.get("channel_id").send(`Left the server ${guild.name}`);
})
```